# react component is passing down the default value of useState instead of passing the API data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios, state

I have this API call in my parent component.

I am trying to pass down it's data as props to be consumed by their child components.

The data that the component is passing is the initial state of the variable instead of the API data. This messes up the rest of the application.

This is my code

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Playlists from './Playlists';
import PlaylistFilter from './PlaylistFilter';
import axios from 'axios';

function App() {
    const [filters, setFilters] = useState(['initial state'])
    const [playlists, setPlaylists] = useState([])

    useEffect( ()=> {
      axios.get(`/api/filters`)
      .then(res => setFilters(res.data.filters))
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }, [])
    //console.log(filters)

    useEffect( ()=> {
      axios.get(`/api/playlists`)
      .then(res => setPlaylists(res.data.filters))
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }, [])
    //console.log(playlists)


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <PlaylistFilter filters={filters} />
      <Playlists playlists={playlists} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

(also the URLs are like that because I have configured the proxy in my package.json)

when I was checking the API call with console.log it was running it a first time showing only the default values and then it printed the API call 3 more times like so
[image: this is the console.log of the values of the API call]

Comment: Are you setting the props to the state in the child components?

Comment: if you are starting with react, anew, then, try practicing with something small. second, instead of console, start debugging with react components in firefox. See if data is being returned and sent down the components. right now, you are doing two api calls, and trying to get both done. not the best approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to only render the app once both `filters` and `playlists` have been populated. Set their initial state to undefined or null, then use conditional rendering:

```
function App() {
    const [filters, setFilters] = useState();
    const [playlists, setPlaylists] = useState();
    // ...

    return (
        <div className="App">
            {
                filters && playlists && (<>
                    <PlaylistFilter filters={filters} />
                    <Playlists playlists={playlists} />
                </>)
            }
        </div>
    );
}
```

This way, if `PlaylistFilter` and `Playlists` expect the initial prop passed down to be populated, they won't choke up on initial mount.

Comment: thank you!!!! it worked, just needed to include empty tags around the components